# How to read file with special characters? - C

Tags: c, unicode, special-characters

I have a countries.txt document in which lists countries' names in spanish language. That means that there are " ´ " and " ñ " characters for example.

I have a small function that I use to count the lines in the document, which originally was made with `fgets()` function, and I edited it so it uses `fgetws()`, since I understand that special characters shoud be stored in `wchar_t` variables.

```
  int linesCount = 0;
    wchar_t line[MAX_SIZE];

    while(fgetws(line, sizeof(line), f) != NULL){
        linesCount++;
    }
    rewind(f);

    return linesCount;
}
```

1) If the function finds a string which contains " ´ ", the program crashes.
2) If there are not any special characters found, valgrind finds a lot more memory leaks instead of just 1 if there is at least one special character like "ñ".

This is the main:

```
int main (void)
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
 countries = fopen("countries.txt", "r");
 int counCount = count_lines(countries);
 fclose(countries);
}
```

This is the first part of countries.txt:

```
Aruba
Angola
Albania
Andorra
Argelia
Armenia
Austria
Alemania
Antártida
Argentina
```

The program crashes when it reachs to "Antártida", which has the " á " letter.

I attach the error valgrind shows:

```
1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==16211== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16211==    at 0x4FCB443: __wmemchr_avx2 (memchr-avx2.S:97)
==16211==    by 0x4EBE164: _IO_getwline_info (iogetwline.c:86)
==16211==    by 0x4EBDD2C: fgetws (iofgetws.c:53)
==16211==    by 0x108BC3: count_lines (people_generator.c:10)
==16211==    by 0x108B3C: main (main.c:15)
==16211==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==16211==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16211==    by 0x4EBB858: _IO_wfile_doallocate (wfiledoalloc.c:79)
==16211==    by 0x4ECA378: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:365)
==16211==    by 0x4EC172B: _IO_wfile_underflow (wfileops.c:179)
==16211==    by 0x4EBF691: _IO_wdefault_uflow (wgenops.c:204)
==16211==    by 0x4EBE1C0: _IO_getwline_info (iogetwline.c:61)
==16211==    by 0x4EBDD2C: fgetws (iofgetws.c:53)
==16211==    by 0x108BC3: count_lines (people_generator.c:10)
==16211==    by 0x108B3C: main (main.c:15)
```

Comment: Well, `valgrind` output is not very helpful unless you include the parts of your code that allocate the memory you are using? (if that is your whole code then it must be an unmasked system allocation that is having issues.) Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the character encoding of the file `countries.txt`?  What is the value of the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable?

Comment: You should read the file in binary mode as `char` and do the character set conversion yourself, so you know what's going on.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I completed the post with more information that I think it makes valgrind output more useful

Comment: @rtx13 I've just checked, and notepad says it is UTF-8. And I don't actually know what LC_CTYPE is. I'm not quite advanced at C programming

Comment: @MarkRansom would you please elaborate more? What would "doing the character set conversion" come to be?

Comment: Your `setlocale` looks bogus.  Please run `locale -a` in your terminal to see what locales are valid on your system.  You're looking for something like `es_XX.utf8`, where XX is your 2-letter country code.

Comment: It works if you set the locale to something valid that `locale -a` returns.  https://repl.it/repls/NimbleIdioticRhombus

Comment: @rtx13 [The Microsoft C run-time library implementation also supports these language strings: american, american english, american-english, australian, ...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/language-strings?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @MemReflect that is interesting, but looks very non-portable.  It also doesn't appear to capture the character encoding which could be critical in this case.

Comment: @rtx13 It's definitely not portable. Windows still uses IBM "code pages" rather than character encodings for example, with special strings like "ACP" or "OCP" to get the default code page for that locale. [The full list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Intl/code-page-identifiers)

Comment: [It's really annoying honestly:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/locale-names-languages-and-country-region-strings?view=vs-2019) _For example, if you specify "Greek_Greece.ACP" as the locale, the locale is stored as Greek_Greece.1253 (the ANSI code page for Greek), and if you specify "Greek_Greece.OCP" as the locale, it is stored as Greek_Greece.737 (the OEM code page for Greek)._

Comment: I believe your choices are `"es_ES.UTF-8"` or `"es_ES"` (for ISO-8859-1) or possibly `"es_ES@euro"` (for ISO-8859-15) (though the `"es"` part can vary depending on your location)

Comment: @Santiago that would very much depend on the encoding of the input file, and you haven't even determined that yet.  That's step 1.  If notepad says UTF-8 that's a good start, but it may just be guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The file, as kept on dis, don't use "wchars" - it will be encoded in an "encoding", most often utf-8, or latin-1.

What you might be getting there is that "spanish" does not give information about the charset encoding - so although you get no error on your call to `setlocale, you are likely trying to read an utf-8 file (which has a multi-byte encoding), with a charmap (one byte per character) encoding.

If you only have to count lines, just use chars, and your program will work as you expect.

So, instead of trying to guess, read this **now**: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

After that you should be able to determine your file encoding, using other tools at your disposal, and then set the correct encoding onyour set-locale call. One of  "es_ES.UTF-8" or "es_ES.ISO8859-1" should work.

Then, if you have a "real-world" task of having to deal with international text-files this simple, I strongly suggest you to move away from C and use a higher-level language. ou will still have to know the file encoding - but life will be an order of magnitude (at least) easier.